# Plot Legends size

Tags: plotting, graphics, gui-construction, text

I use 2 similar `Manipulate`: the difference between one and the other is only the function that they draw.

```
Manipulate[Plot[{a1*Sin[x1],Sin[x1]}, {x1, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange->{-4,4},
         PlotLegends->{"y=a sin(x)","y=sin(x)"}],
         {{a1, 1,"a"}, 0.1, 4, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

I put them in two different places of the notebook, but one of them have the text in the legend bigger than the other: how can I manually set that textsixe?

Comment: Wrap the legend text in `Style["y=a sin(x)", 14]` where 14 is the font size. You should have complete control over the text size using `Style`

Comment: Yes, it seems working